# Create MVC app in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Does Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web allow creating MVC applications and hybrid apps that are MVC as well as usable on mobile devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2013 Express for Web allows for creating any ASP.NET projects that the full version can create.  This includes MVC, WebForms, and WebAPI.  It is a perfectly viable tool for any web site; the features you'll miss from the full version are tooling features such as performance and code analysis, extensibility features (of VS), etc.